# Linux: how to know who deleted my user account

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, system-administration

I have a regular username on a linux machine. I also have the root privilege. Today I found my username was deleted. That is, if I logged in as root and then ran

```
su myusername
```

The systems said "myusername" does not exist. I checked file /etc/passwd and "myusername" was not there.

My question is, is there anyway to find out who deleted "myusername"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because either you destroyed your account yourself without realizing it, or something else did. Anyway, programming will not solve your problem.

Comment: Try looking here: http://serverfault.com/questions/208347/how-do-i-list-all-users-with-root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
grep "deluser" /home/*/.bash_history /root/.bash_history
```